# What Functions Behave like a Normal Distribution?

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution

This is a pretty open-ended question, but I thought I may ask. The normal distribution that is generally used is taken on a variation of the equation: $$y=e^{-x^2} $$

But I've noticed that there are quite a few other functions that behave like this:
$$y=\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$
$$y=\operatorname{sech}(x)$$
$$y=\arctan(\frac{1}{x^2})$$

It's pretty apparent that most of them have some form of $x^2$ in them, and I know the $\operatorname{sech}(x)$ actually has a name (hyperbolic secant distribution). What other functions behave like this? And can they all be used the same way as the normal distribution?

Comment: You'll need to clarify what you mean by "used the same way as the normal distribution"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I mean using it like a continuous probabilistic distribution. I don't exactly know what I'm talking about, but does that help at all?

Comment: Your first example can be thought of as an instance of the [Cauchy distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution), which is interesting in that it has an undefined mean and variance

Comment: Any function $f(x)$ for which $f(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$ and for which $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ is finite (such as $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$) can be scaled to make a probability distribution.  Perhaps this is what you're trying to ask.

Comment: The fact that $x^2$ is in most of them is cause the shape requires it to be an even function, and one easy way to make even functions is to consider functions of $x^2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many curves are "bell shaped".  The ones you mention are examples.

But the normal density goes to zero (as $x \to \infty$) at a certain rate, not shared by some other bell shaped curves.

$\arctan(1/x^2)$ and $1/(1+x^2)$ go to zero only at the rate $O(1/x^2)$, which is much slower than $\exp(-x^2)$.

$\mathrm{sech}(x)$ goes to zero at the rate $O(\exp(-x))$ which, although much faster than $O(1/x^2)$, is still much slower than $\exp(-x^2)$.

Can these others be used in the same way as the normal density?  No, only the normal density works in the Central Limit Theorem.